# Comparing two dates without taking time into account

Tags: date, go

I have two dates like this, I would like to compare only the dates, ignoring the time. Currently I have this:

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    //"fmt"
)

func main() {
    a, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2017-02-01T12:00:00+00:00")
    b, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2017-02-11T14:30:00+00:00")

    x := b.Sub(a)

    println(int(x.Hours()))
}
```

Which prints `242`. That is correct, but what I actually want to do is compare the dates like this:

```
    a, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2017-02-01T00:00:00+00:00")
    b, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2017-02-11T00:00:00+00:00")
```

Notice: minutes/hours/seconds have been set to zero - the diff will now be 240 hours.

I couldn't really figure out how to do this, is there a `time.SetTime(0, 0, 0)` function in Go that I missed or what's the canonical way to reset the time for a date?

Comment: Do you still want to factor in the timezone? For example, `2017-01-01T22:00:00+00:00` and `2017-01-02T02:00:00+04:00` are the same moment in time - But are described with different time zones.

Comment: That's a good question, the dates I work with are assumed UTC, so it doesn''t matter that much. But if they had different time zones, I would need to take that into account.

Comment: Well, in that case, eugenioy's answer seems to cover it. FYI - their answer does take the timezones into account, so those two dates I mentioned would be considered the same day, and thus 0 hours apart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [`Truncate`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Truncate) the times to make them round to a multiple of a day.

In your example:

```
oneDay := 24 * time.Hour
a = a.Truncate(oneDay)
b = b.Truncate(oneDay)
```

Find a playground with the adapted code here: https://play.golang.org/p/yWIYt3UkiT

Comment: Ok, I see. I read through the API docs before but wasn't sure what to make out of the `Truncate` method. I will give this a try, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be rather careful handling dates if using time.Time because there can be edge cases around the beginning and ending of daylight savings.

Shameless plug: I wrote a Date package (actually it was derived from someone else's earlier work) to deal with dates without incurring the DST issues.

https://github.com/rickb777/date

You can do, for example,

```
a := date.New(2017, 2, 1)
b := date.New(2017, 2, 11)
daysDifference := b.Sub(a)
fmt.Println(daysDifference)
```

---

There are other sub-packages to handle date ranges, timespans, ISO8601 periods and clock-face time.